# C++17 create directories automatically given a file path

Tags: c++, file, ubuntu, filesystems, filepath

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    ofstream fo("output/folder1/data/today/log.txt");
    fo << "Hello world\n";
    fo.close();
    
    return 0;
}
```

I need to output some log data to some files with variable names. However, `ofstream` does not create directories along the way, if the path to the file doesn't exist, `ofstream` writes to nowhere!

What can I do to automatically create folders along a file path? The system is Ubuntu only.

Comment: [`std::filesystem::create_directories`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) (C++17)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this function (`CreateDirectoryRecursive`) to achieve that, as shown below.

It uses [`std::filesystem::create_directories`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) and [`std::filesystem::exists`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists).

```
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

// Returns:
//   true upon success.
//   false upon failure, and set the std::error_code & err accordingly.
bool CreateDirectoryRecursive(std::string const & dirName, std::error_code & err)
{
    err.clear();
    if (!std::filesystem::create_directories(dirName, err))
    {
        if (std::filesystem::exists(dirName))
        {
            // The folder already exists:
            err.clear();
            return true;    
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::error_code err;
    if (!CreateDirectoryRecursive("/tmp/a/b/c", err))
    {
        // Report the error:
        std::cout << "CreateDirectoryRecursive FAILED, err: " << err.message() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

[`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) is available since c++-17.
Before that it was available in many compilers via the [`<experimental/filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/experimental/filesystem) header.

Comment: Which part of that code requires C++20? An why do you wrap the std function instead of calling it direct?

Comment: Console output in a utility function is a pretty bad idea: It might spoil the output otherwise provided, maybe in a different language! Here just one single reason for failure – if there are more of, then rather create an enum with distinct values for each error type end return that one, leaving any output/logging to the user – or just the one of the standard library in this case.

Comment: @Aconcagua I agree in general about console output. The code above was just an example how to achieve the directory creation. In production code I all errors should be reported properly.

Comment: @wohlstad Yes, my question was not correct formulated. I wanted to ask which part of your code requires the experimental prefix in C++17.  And according to this (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) the answer is nothing.

Comment: `experimental` is just not provided by all compilers...

Comment: Updated the answer, moved the `experimental` stuff to a note, and removed console output from inside the function.

Answer (score 3):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory):

```
bool create_directories(const std::filesystem::path& p);
```

Creates a directory for every element of `p` that does not already exist. If `p` already exists, the function does nothing. It returns `true` if a directory was created for the directory `p` resolves to, `false` otherwise.

What you can do is:

1. Get the directory path in which you want to save your file to (in your example: `output/folder1/data/today/`).
2. Get your file name (`log.txt`).
3. Create (all of) your folder(s).
4. Write to your file using an `std::fstream`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

// Split a string separated by sep into a vector
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str, const char sep)
{
    std::string token; 
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    
    while (std::getline(ss, token, sep)) {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }
    
    return tokens;
}

int main()
{
    std::string path = "output/folder1/data/today/log.txt";
    
    std::vector<std::string> dirs = split(path, '/');
    
    if (dirs.empty())
        return 1;
    
    std::string tmp = "./"; // Current dir
    for (auto it = dirs.begin(); it != std::prev(dirs.end()); ++it)
        tmp += *it + '/';
    
    fs::create_directories(tmp);
    
    std::ofstream os(tmp + dirs.back());
    os << "Some text...\n";
    os.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But there's no need to do all those split I think, there's the function `filepath.parent_path()` to get the folder